# How to fuse Visual SLAM (ORB_SLAM2) with detected obstacle using 2D Lidar and IMU to obtain robot localization?

Tags: c++, localization, ros, robotics, slam

I would like to fuse Visual SLAM (ORB_SLAM2) with detected obstacle using 2D Lidar and IMU to obtain robot localization(lateral position and heading angle of the robot). Already successfully detected the obstacles around using the 2D Lidar. So from my code I have the Center X,Y of the obstacle and also the angle.  Here the obstacle detection code. Also the scan_matching node gives 2DPose

```
#include "../include/obstacle_detector.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace obstacle_detector;

ObstacleDetector::ObstacleDetector() : nh_(""), nh_local_("~") {
  updateParams();

  if (p_use_scan_)
    scan_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("/scan", 1, &ObstacleDetector::scanCallback, this);
  else if (p_use_pcl_)
    pcl_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("pcl", 10, &ObstacleDetector::pclCallback, this);

  obstacles_pub_ = nh_.advertise<obstacle_detector::Obstacles>("obstacles", 5);

  ROS_INFO("Obstacle Detector [OK]");
  ros::spin();
}

void ObstacleDetector::updateParams() {
  nh_local_.param<std::string>("world_frame", p_world_frame_, "world");
  nh_local_.param<std::string>("scanner_frame", p_scanner_frame_, "laser_frame");

  nh_local_.param<bool>("use_scan", p_use_scan_, true);
  nh_local_.param<bool>("use_pcl", p_use_pcl_, false);
  nh_local_.param<bool>("transform_to_world", p_transform_to_world, true);
  nh_local_.param<bool>("use_split_and_merge", p_use_split_and_merge_, false);

  nh_local_.param<int>("min_group_points", p_min_group_points_, 3);

  nh_local_.param<double>("max_group_distance", p_max_group_distance_, 0.100);
  nh_local_.param<double>("distance_proportion", p_distance_proportion_, 0.006136);
  nh_local_.param<double>("max_split_distance", p_max_split_distance_, 0.100);
  nh_local_.param<double>("max_merge_separation", p_max_merge_separation_, 0.200);
  nh_local_.param<double>("max_merge_spread", p_max_merge_spread_, 0.070);
  nh_local_.param<double>("max_circle_radius", p_max_circle_radius_, 0.300);
  nh_local_.param<double>("radius_enlargement", p_radius_enlargement_, 0.050);

  nh_local_.param<double>("max_scanner_range", p_max_scanner_range_, 5.0);
  nh_local_.param<double>("max_x_range", p_max_x_range_, 2.0);
  nh_local_.param<double>("min_x_range", p_min_x_range_, -2.0);
  nh_local_.param<double>("max_y_range", p_max_y_range_, 2.0);
  nh_local_.param<double>("min_y_range", p_min_y_range_, -2.0);
}

void ObstacleDetector::scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan) {
  initial_points_.clear();

  double phi = scan->angle_min - scan->angle_increment;

  for (const float r : scan->ranges) {
    phi += scan->angle_increment;

    if (r >= scan->range_min && r <= scan->range_max && r <= p_max_scanner_range_)
      initial_points_.push_back(Point::fromPoolarCoords(r, phi));
  }

  processPoints();
}

void ObstacleDetector::pclCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud::ConstPtr& pcl) {
  initial_points_.clear();

  for (const geometry_msgs::Point32& p : pcl->points)
    if (Point(p.x, p.y).lengthSquared() <= pow(p_max_scanner_range_, 2.0))
      initial_points_.push_back(Point(p.x, p.y));

  processPoints();
}

void ObstacleDetector::processPoints() {
  segments_.clear();
  circles_.clear();

  groupPointsAndDetectSegments();
  mergeSegments();

  detectCircles();
  mergeCircles();

  if (p_transform_to_world)
    transformToWorld();

  publishObstacles();
}

void ObstacleDetector::groupPointsAndDetectSegments() {
  list<Point> point_set;

  for (const Point& point : initial_points_) {
    if (point_set.size() != 0) {
      double r = point.length();

      if ((point - point_set.back()).lengthSquared() > pow(p_max_group_distance_ + r * p_distance_proportion_, 2.0)) {
        detectSegments(point_set);
        point_set.clear();
      }
    }
    point_set.push_back(point);
  }

  detectSegments(point_set); // Check the last point set too!
}

void ObstacleDetector::detectSegments(list<Point>& point_set) {
  if (point_set.size() < p_min_group_points_)
    return;

  Segment segment(Point(0.0, 0.0), Point(1.0, 0.0));
  if (p_use_split_and_merge_)
    segment = fitSegment(point_set);
  else // Use Iterative End Point Fit
    segment = Segment(point_set.front(), point_set.back());

  list<Point>::iterator set_divider;
  double max_distance = 0.0;
  double distance     = 0.0;

  // Seek the point of division; omit first and last point of the set
  for (auto point_itr = ++point_set.begin(); point_itr != --point_set.end(); ++point_itr) {
    if ((distance = segment.distanceTo(*point_itr)) >= max_distance) {
      double r = (*point_itr).length();

      if (distance > p_max_split_distance_ + r * p_distance_proportion_) {
        max_distance = distance;
        set_divider = point_itr;
      }
    }
  }

  if (max_distance > 0.0) { // Split the set
    point_set.insert(set_divider, *set_divider);  // Clone the dividing point for each group

    list<Point> subset1, subset2;
    subset1.splice(subset1.begin(), point_set, point_set.begin(), set_divider);
    subset2.splice(subset2.begin(), point_set, set_divider, point_set.end());

    detectSegments(subset1);
    detectSegments(subset2);
  } else {  // Add the segment
    if (!p_use_split_and_merge_)
      segment = fitSegment(point_set);

    if (segment.length() > 0.0) {
      segments_.push_back(segment);
      segments_.back().point_set().assign(point_set.begin(), point_set.end());
    }
  }
}

void ObstacleDetector::mergeSegments() {
  for (auto i = segments_.begin(); i != segments_.end(); ++i) {
    auto j = i;
    for (++j; j != segments_.end(); ++j) {
      if (compareAndMergeSegments(*i, *j)) {  // If merged - a new segment appeared at the end of the list
        auto temp_ptr = i;
        i = segments_.insert(i, segments_.back()); // Copy new segment in place; i now points to new segment
        segments_.pop_back();       // Remove the new segment from the back of the list
        segments_.erase(temp_ptr);  // Remove the first merged segment
        segments_.erase(j);         // Remove the second merged segment
        if (i != segments_.begin())
          i--;                      // The for loop will increment i so let it point to new segment in next iteration
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

bool ObstacleDetector::compareAndMergeSegments(Segment& s1, Segment& s2) {
  if (&s1 == &s2)
    return false;

  // Segments must be provided counter-clockwise
  if (s1.first_point().cross(s2.first_point()) < 0.0)
    return compareAndMergeSegments(s2, s1);

  if ((s1.last_point() - s2.first_point()).length() < p_max_merge_separation_) {
    list<Point> merged_points;
    merged_points.insert(merged_points.begin(), s1.point_set().begin(), s1.point_set().end());
    merged_points.insert(merged_points.end(), s2.point_set().begin(), s2.point_set().end());

    Segment s = fitSegment(merged_points);

    if (s.distanceTo(s1.first_point()) < p_max_merge_spread_ &&
        s.distanceTo(s1.last_point())  < p_max_merge_spread_ &&
        s.distanceTo(s2.first_point()) < p_max_merge_spread_ &&
        s.distanceTo(s2.last_point())  < p_max_merge_spread_) {
      segments_.push_back(s);
      segments_.back().point_set().assign(merged_points.begin(), merged_points.end());
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

void ObstacleDetector::detectCircles() {
  for (const Segment& s : segments_) {
    Circle c(s);
    c.setRadius(c.radius() + p_radius_enlargement_);

    if (c.radius() < p_max_circle_radius_)
      circles_.push_back(c);
  }
}

void ObstacleDetector::mergeCircles() {
  for (auto i = circles_.begin(); i != circles_.end(); ++i) {
    auto j = i;
    for (++j; j != circles_.end(); ++j) {
      if (compareAndMergeCircles(*i, *j)) {      // If merged - a new circle appeared at the end of the list
        auto temp_ptr = i;
        i = circles_.insert(i, circles_.back()); // i now points to new circle
        circles_.pop_back();
        circles_.erase(temp_ptr);
        circles_.erase(j);
        if (i != circles_.begin())
          --i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

bool ObstacleDetector::compareAndMergeCircles(Circle& c1, Circle& c2) {
  // If circle c1 is fully inside c2 - merge and leave as c2
  if (c1.radius() + (c2.center() - c1.center()).length() <= c2.radius()) {
    circles_.push_back(c2);
    return true;
  }

  // If circle c2 is fully inside c1 - merge and leave as c1
  if (c2.radius() + (c2.center() - c1.center()).length() <= c1.radius()) {
    circles_.push_back(c1);
    return true;
  }

  // If circles intersect and are 'small' - merge
  if (c1.radius() + c2.radius() >= (c2.center() - c1.center()).length()) {
    Segment s(c1.center(), c2.center());
    Circle c(s);
    c.setRadius(c.radius() + max(c1.radius(), c2.radius()));

    if (c.radius() < p_max_circle_radius_) {
      circles_.push_back(c);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void ObstacleDetector::transformToWorld() {
  geometry_msgs::PointStamped point_l;  // Point in local (scanner) coordinate frame
  geometry_msgs::PointStamped point_w;  // Point in global (world) coordinate frame

  point_l.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  point_l.header.frame_id = p_scanner_frame_;

  point_w.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  point_w.header.frame_id = p_world_frame_;

  try {
    tf_listener_.waitForTransform(p_world_frame_, p_scanner_frame_, ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(3.0));

    for (auto it = circles_.begin(); it != circles_.end(); ++it) {
      if (it->center().x < p_max_x_range_ && it->center().x > p_min_x_range_ &&
          it->center().y < p_max_y_range_ && it->center().y > p_min_y_range_)
      {
        point_l.point.x = it->center().x;
        point_l.point.y = it->center().y;
        tf_listener_.transformPoint(p_world_frame_, point_l, point_w);
        it->setCenter(point_w.point.x, point_w.point.y);
      }
      else {
        it = circles_.erase(it);
        --it;
      }
    }

    for (Segment& s : segments_) {
      point_l.point.x = s.first_point().x;
      point_l.point.y = s.first_point().y;
      tf_listener_.transformPoint(p_world_frame_, point_l, point_w);
      s.setFirstPoint(point_w.point.x, point_w.point.y);

      point_l.point.x = s.last_point().x;
      point_l.point.y = s.last_point().y;
      tf_listener_.transformPoint(p_world_frame_, point_l, point_w);
      s.setLastPoint(point_w.point.x, point_w.point.y);
    }
  }
  catch (tf::TransformException ex) {
    ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
    ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
  }
}

void ObstacleDetector::publishObstacles() {
  Obstacles obstacles;
  obstacles.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

  if (p_transform_to_world)
    obstacles.header.frame_id = p_world_frame_;
  else
    obstacles.header.frame_id = p_scanner_frame_;

  for (const Segment& s : segments_) {
    obstacle_detector::SegmentObstacle segment;

    segment.first_point.x = s.first_point().x;
    segment.first_point.y = s.first_point().y;
    segment.last_point.x = s.last_point().x;
    segment.last_point.y = s.last_point().y;

    obstacles.segments.push_back(segment);
  }

  for (const Circle& c : circles_) {
    obstacle_detector::CircleObstacle circle;

    circle.center.x = c.center().x;
    circle.center.y = c.center().y;
    circle.radius = c.radius();

    obstacles.circles.push_back(circle);
  }

  obstacles_pub_.publish(obstacles);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "obstacle_detector");
  ObstacleDetector od;
  return 0;
}
```

So now I would like to update the robot’s estimated pose by fusing the result with the Visual SLAM (ORB_SLAM2) , because the 2D LIDAR can’t estimate the longitudinal position.So with visual SLAM fusion will have information about the desired position in the isle.But Im not sure how to fuse them. Any help?

Comment: im looking for the solution in this direction (A Novel Approach for Lidar-Based Robot
Localization in a Scale-Drifted Map Constructed
Using Monocular SLAM) . Preferably in some github or ros packages that can be used and modified adapt for my case

Comment: What about [robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html)? From the Docs: *Support for multiple ROS message types. All state estimation nodes in robot_localization can take in nav_msgs/Odometry, sensor_msgs/Imu, geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped, or geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped messages.*

Comment: it doesn't take Images. I need online visual slam to correct  the pose from the lidar and close the loop

Comment: Oh you need something that does visual SLAM? I thought you have this already. Then you could use `robot_localization` to fuse `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` with IMU and so on. For packages that do visual Odometry, I'm not sure which one is best. Never used this.

Comment: I have visual SLAM but is not that good because sometimes is lost . So I can get help of the lidar to improve the pose

Comment: Then use all this information in an EKF and merge them. You need an covariance matrix for each input. If you don't want to write your own one. You can use robot_localization.

Comment: how about Rtabmap localization  or Google cartographer (https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer_ros)?

Comment: so I have the following topics that can help me for the lokalization. 1. Current speed and yawrate calculated from wheel speed.  2 /robot/data/twist  Twist data created from vehicle speed and IMU data. 3. /robot/data/vslam_localization/pose  Output pose from ORB_SLAM 4. /camera/left/image_raw and /camera/right/image_raw  Images from camera 5. /scan  YDLidar scan 6./imu/sensor_msgs/Imu  IMU data from Inuitive camera  And the following tf
/tf
- map : map frame
- odom : odom frame
- base_link : vehicle pose (center of driving wheel axis)
- slam_base : a frame where ORB_SLAM is working

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here are some things I would suggest:

- R. Rajamani, Vehicle Dynamics and Control, Springer Science & Business Media, 2011. ISBN 0-387-26396-9
- [How ROS Navigation does it](https://navigation.ros.org/concepts/index.html#state-estimation)
- `robot_localization`

  - [Talk](https://vimeo.com/142624091)
  - [Dokumentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html)

---

You say you have the following data/topics:

1. Current speed and yawrate calculated from wheel speed.
2. /robot/data/twist Twist data created from vehicle speed and IMU data.
3. /robot/data/vslam_localization/pose Output pose from ORB_SLAM
4. /camera/left/image_raw and /camera/right/image_raw Images from camera
5. /scan YDLidar scan
6. /imu/sensor_msgs/Imu IMU data

---

Here is what I would do:

###### Create raw odometry

Use the sensor data from your motors to create a [`nav_msgs/Odometry`](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) topic. This should not include imu data.

###### Create pose from lidar and map

This can be done with e.g. [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) to get [`geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html).

###### Add confidence as covariance matrix to ORB SLAM2 pose

Not too sure how I would do this. From a quick look at the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/orb_slam2_ros). ORB SLAM publishes only a tf frame from which you extract the pose, I assume. To be able to merge this data you need a measurement of confidence in form of a covariance matrix. There ore multiple ways to add this. The "simple" way, would be to calculate a static covariance matrix from some test data. The "good" way would be to use ORB SLAM2's confidence to create the covariance matrix dynamically.

##### Merging/Fusing all the data together

Here I would suggest [`robot_localization`](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html). Using the following data:

- Your raw odometry data [`nav_msgs/Odometry`](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html)
- Your IMU data [`sensor_msgs/Imu`](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html)
- AMCL's pose estimation from map and lidar [`geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html)
- ORM SLAM2's pose estimation from your cameras [`geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html)

Make sure that all those topics have correct time stamps and a valid covariance matrix. All the input data should also be independent (in a sense of never using the same sensor information twice) of one another.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Will try it. I have one question regarding raw odometry . So from /robot/data/vehicle_state  Current speed and yawrate calculated from wheel speed   can be used as nav_msgs/Odometry topic?

Comment: Yes, you do dead reckoning and integrate the speed and direction to get an continues pose estimate. This integration will accumulate the error and will get worse over time. You need to estimate this error and publish it as covariance matrix in `nav_msgs/Odometry.pose.covariance`. If you have twist information as well, you can publish them in `nav_msgs/Odometry.twist` as well. A constant covariance matrix will probably  be sufficient, because the error is only the measuring error which is probably time invariant. If you want more literature on dead reckoning I recommend the book  I suggested.

Comment: I know that. Well at the end my goal is not ICP or visual slam. My goal is to use LiDAR to detect the driving are( means walls) and use that to correct the Visual slam pose. Means not doing ICP. What I want is detecting walls (like clusters) and get the distance and angle to the robot. Now I wonna use this info to correct the pose from Visual. slam. . But I need more details how to do that. Think can use ROS TF for this correct? Any help ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to detect walls and their angle, I think you need custom code for that. I don't know any package that does this out of the box. But lets say you have that. Than there is a constant offset from the pose of your LiDAR to your robot base and to your camera. This constant offset should be set in den URDF/Xacro file which is loaded into the `robot_description` parameter. Then you need `robot_state_publisher` to publish the const transforms and the you can use `tf2` to correct for this.

Comment: I already have a node that detect the  walls and shelves. Also have a node that get the distance and angle from the mobile robot to the (walls and shelves). Now I want to estimate he robot pose relative to that area(walls and shelves) and update (correct)  the estimate robot pose  from visual  slam (because its drifting with the time).So I do correction and more accurate pose using 2D Lidar and detecting the area where robot moves.

Comment: So you want to know how to calculate the most likely position based on the distance to nearby objects (walls) which have a known position? You can do this with a least squares estimator, but this should be a new SO question if you have trouble with that. Your estimator should output a `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` which can be feed to the ekf of `robot_localization`.

Comment: I dont know upfront the nearby objects (walls) position, but while the robot is moving around I can detect them and get their coordinates. For example I can get this infos from ros topics. aveD: [2.0390000343322754, 1.9795000553131104, 1.874500036239624]
minD: [1.9830000400543213, 1.9259999990463257, 1.8459999561309814]
angle: [5.325444066486003, 5.857979633083888, 5.325443403329952]
size: [0.22001850605010986, 0.23771557211875916, 0.18730825185775757]
first_point:
      x: 2.4642263071
      y: -0.078741734
      
    last_point:
      x: 2.4741690035
      y: 0.0585282418

Comment: Is this clear now? So in real time (online) I detect the nearby objects(wall), get their distance , angle and coordinate .

Comment: and this least squares estimator can be linear or I have to consider non linear one? Or should open new question?